# aws autoscaling attach-load-balancer-target-groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

Good afternoon. I am trying to add an instance to the target group as it is written in the aws manual: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/attach-load-balancer-target-groups.html but for some reason it does not work . aws cli

```
aws autoscaling attach-load-balancer-target-groups --auto-scaling-group-name awseb-e-txwhwjxk75-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-14CH3JZ6DNIPT --target-group-arns arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-central-1:063129209410:targetgroup/aifit-cc-qa/d9d8c7a85f2ea7df
```

The instance is not added, there are no errors in the console:

```
 aws cli version - aws-cli/1.18.52 Python/3.6.9 Linux/5.3.0-51-generic botocore/1.16.2


UPD. debug `root@HP:/home/bell# aws --version
aws-cli/2.0.10 Python/3.7.3 Linux/5.3.0-51-generic botocore/2.0.0dev14
root@HP:/home/bell# aws --debug autoscaling attach-load-balancer-target-groups --auto-scaling-group-name awseb-e-txwhwjxk75-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-14CH3JZ6DNIPT --target-group-arns arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-central-1:063129209410:targetgroup/aifit-cc-qa/d9d8c7a85f2ea7df
2020-05-06 10:31:19,636 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - CLI version: aws-cli/2.0.10 Python/3.7.3 Linux/5.3.0-51-generic botocore/2.0.0dev14
2020-05-06 10:31:19,641 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Arguments entered to CLI: ['--debug', 'autoscaling', 'attach-load-balancer-target-groups', '--auto-scaling-group-name', 'awseb-e-txwhwjxk75-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-14CH3JZ6DNIPT', '--target-group-arns', 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-central-1:063129209410:targetgroup/aifit-cc-qa/d9d8c7a85f2ea7df']
2020-05-06 10:31:19,641 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function add_timestamp_parser at 0x7f18da53b158>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,641 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function register_uri_param_handler at 0x7f18dae1d400>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,642 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function add_binary_formatter at 0x7f18da502620>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,644 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function inject_assume_role_provider_cache at 0x7f18dae45400>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,646 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function attach_history_handler at 0x7f18da685bf8>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,646 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function inject_json_file_cache at 0x7f18da6bd598>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,662 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/2.0.10/dist/botocore/data/autoscaling/2011-01-01/service-2.json
2020-05-06 10:31:19,673 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.autoscaling: calling handler <function add_waiters at 0x7f18da546598>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,680 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - OrderedDict([('auto-scaling-group-name', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x7f18da38c0b8>), ('target-group-arns', <awscli.arguments.ListArgument object at 0x7f18da391780>)])
2020-05-06 10:31:19,680 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.autoscaling.attach-load-balancer-target-groups: calling handler <function add_streaming_output_arg at 0x7f18da53b400>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,680 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.autoscaling.attach-load-balancer-target-groups: calling handler <function add_cli_input_json at 0x7f18dae45bf8>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,680 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.autoscaling.attach-load-balancer-target-groups: calling handler <function add_cli_input_yaml at 0x7f18dae512f0>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,680 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.autoscaling.attach-load-balancer-target-groups: calling handler <function unify_paging_params at 0x7f18da6bed08>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,686 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/2.0.10/dist/botocore/data/autoscaling/2011-01-01/paginators-1.json
2020-05-06 10:31:19,687 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.autoscaling.attach-load-balancer-target-groups: calling handler <function add_generate_skeleton at 0x7f18da59c9d8>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,687 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.autoscaling.attach-load-balancer-target-groups: calling handler <function add_auto_prompt at 0x7f18da502598>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,687 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.autoscaling.attach-load-balancer-target-groups: calling handler <bound method OverrideRequiredArgsArgument.override_required_args of <awscli.customizations.cliinput.CliInputJSONArgument object at 0x7f18da3917b8>>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,687 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.autoscaling.attach-load-balancer-target-groups: calling handler <bound method OverrideRequiredArgsArgument.override_required_args of <awscli.customizations.cliinput.CliInputYAMLArgument object at 0x7f18da3918d0>>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,687 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.autoscaling.attach-load-balancer-target-groups: calling handler <bound method GenerateCliSkeletonArgument.override_required_args of <awscli.customizations.generatecliskeleton.GenerateCliSkeletonArgument object at 0x7f18da391940>>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,687 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.autoscaling.attach-load-balancer-target-groups: calling handler <bound method AutoPromptArgument.override_required_args of <awscli.customizations.autoprompt.AutoPromptArgument object at 0x7f18da393e10>>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,693 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.autoscaling.attach-load-balancer-target-groups.auto-scaling-group-name: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f18da47ffd0>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,694 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event process-cli-arg.autoscaling.attach-load-balancer-target-groups: calling handler <awscli.argprocess.ParamShorthandParser object at 0x7f18dae92dd8>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,694 - MainThread - awscli.arguments - DEBUG - Unpacked value of 'awseb-e-txwhwjxk75-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-14CH3JZ6DNIPT' for parameter "auto_scaling_group_name": 'awseb-e-txwhwjxk75-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-14CH3JZ6DNIPT'
2020-05-06 10:31:19,694 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.autoscaling.attach-load-balancer-target-groups.target-group-arns: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f18da47ffd0>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,694 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event process-cli-arg.autoscaling.attach-load-balancer-target-groups: calling handler <awscli.argprocess.ParamShorthandParser object at 0x7f18dae92dd8>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,694 - MainThread - awscli.arguments - DEBUG - Unpacked value of ['arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-central-1:063129209410:targetgroup/aifit-cc-qa/d9d8c7a85f2ea7df'] for parameter "target_group_arns": ['arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-central-1:063129209410:targetgroup/aifit-cc-qa/d9d8c7a85f2ea7df']
2020-05-06 10:31:19,694 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.autoscaling.attach-load-balancer-target-groups.cli-input-json: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f18da47ffd0>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,694 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.autoscaling.attach-load-balancer-target-groups.cli-input-yaml: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f18da47ffd0>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,694 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.autoscaling.attach-load-balancer-target-groups.generate-cli-skeleton: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f18da47ffd0>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,694 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.autoscaling.attach-load-balancer-target-groups.cli-auto-prompt: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f18da47ffd0>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,694 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event calling-command.autoscaling.attach-load-balancer-target-groups: calling handler <bound method CliInputArgument.add_to_call_parameters of <awscli.customizations.cliinput.CliInputJSONArgument object at 0x7f18da3917b8>>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,695 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event calling-command.autoscaling.attach-load-balancer-target-groups: calling handler <bound method CliInputArgument.add_to_call_parameters of <awscli.customizations.cliinput.CliInputYAMLArgument object at 0x7f18da3918d0>>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,695 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event calling-command.autoscaling.attach-load-balancer-target-groups: calling handler <bound method GenerateCliSkeletonArgument.generate_skeleton of <awscli.customizations.generatecliskeleton.GenerateCliSkeletonArgument object at 0x7f18da391940>>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,695 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event calling-command.autoscaling.attach-load-balancer-target-groups: calling handler <bound method AutoPromptArgument.auto_prompt_arguments of <awscli.customizations.autoprompt.AutoPromptArgument object at 0x7f18da393e10>>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,695 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: env
2020-05-06 10:31:19,695 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: assume-role
2020-05-06 10:31:19,695 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: assume-role-with-web-identity
2020-05-06 10:31:19,695 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: sso
2020-05-06 10:31:19,695 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: shared-credentials-file
2020-05-06 10:31:19,696 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - INFO - Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials
2020-05-06 10:31:19,697 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/2.0.10/dist/botocore/data/endpoints.json
2020-05-06 10:31:19,705 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choose-service-name: calling handler <function handle_service_name_alias at 0x7f18dbe3a7b8>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,708 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event creating-client-class.auto-scaling: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x7f18dbe8c6a8>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,712 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Setting autoscaling timeout as (60, 60)
2020-05-06 10:31:19,713 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event provide-client-params.auto-scaling.AttachLoadBalancerTargetGroups: calling handler <function base64_decode_input_blobs at 0x7f18da502e18>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,713 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-parameter-build.auto-scaling.AttachLoadBalancerTargetGroups: calling handler <function generate_idempotent_uuid at 0x7f18dbe5b6a8>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,713 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-call.auto-scaling.AttachLoadBalancerTargetGroups: calling handler <function inject_api_version_header_if_needed at 0x7f18dbe5e0d0>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,713 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Making request for OperationModel(name=AttachLoadBalancerTargetGroups) with params: {'url_path': '/', 'query_string': '', 'method': 'POST', 'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8', 'User-Agent': 'aws-cli/2.0.10 Python/3.7.3 Linux/5.3.0-51-generic botocore/2.0.0dev14'}, 'body': {'Action': 'AttachLoadBalancerTargetGroups', 'Version': '2011-01-01', 'AutoScalingGroupName': 'awseb-e-txwhwjxk75-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-14CH3JZ6DNIPT', 'TargetGroupARNs.member.1': 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-central-1:063129209410:targetgroup/aifit-cc-qa/d9d8c7a85f2ea7df'}, 'url': 'https://autoscaling.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/', 'context': {'client_region': 'eu-central-1', 'client_config': <botocore.config.Config object at 0x7f18da18b0b8>, 'has_streaming_input': False, 'auth_type': None}}
2020-05-06 10:31:19,713 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event request-created.auto-scaling.AttachLoadBalancerTargetGroups: calling handler <bound method RequestSigner.handler of <botocore.signers.RequestSigner object at 0x7f18da18b048>>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,713 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choose-signer.auto-scaling.AttachLoadBalancerTargetGroups: calling handler <function set_operation_specific_signer at 0x7f18dbe5b598>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,714 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Calculating signature using v4 auth.
2020-05-06 10:31:19,714 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - CanonicalRequest:
POST
/

content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
host:autoscaling.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:20200506T073119Z

content-type;host;x-amz-date
ba70ad1394364a129f19ff772f06863a805d1770a9d72bbe0d42ca38ba9d468c
2020-05-06 10:31:19,714 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - StringToSign:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20200506T073119Z
20200506/eu-central-1/autoscaling/aws4_request
a79a67df4af15c410777059b1d48efd8e81573ed093ed5d0b6e66b05d407d6c0
2020-05-06 10:31:19,714 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Signature:
9160bb5484cfe8669fbbd172ccd599f1927c90590915df875d393c3aae40c6d5
2020-05-06 10:31:19,714 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Sending http request: <AWSPreparedRequest stream_output=False, method=POST, url=https://autoscaling.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/, headers={'Content-Type': b'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8', 'User-Agent': b'aws-cli/2.0.10 Python/3.7.3 Linux/5.3.0-51-generic botocore/2.0.0dev14', 'X-Amz-Date': b'20200506T073119Z', 'Authorization': b'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAQ5MWLJJBJRFYEGVQ/20200506/eu-central-1/autoscaling/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=9160bb5484cfe8669fbbd172ccd599f1927c90590915df875d393c3aae40c6d5', 'Content-Length': '273'}>
2020-05-06 10:31:19,715 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): autoscaling.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:443
2020-05-06 10:31:20,125 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - https://autoscaling.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:443 "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 289
2020-05-06 10:31:20,127 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response headers: {'x-amzn-RequestId': '27e1a1a4-638e-4d7f-81bc-f37388584eab', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml', 'Content-Length': '289', 'Date': 'Wed, 06 May 2020 07:31:19 GMT'}
2020-05-06 10:31:20,127 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response body:
b'<AttachLoadBalancerTargetGroupsResponse xmlns="http://autoscaling.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-01-01/">\n  <AttachLoadBalancerTargetGroupsResult/>\n  <ResponseMetadata>\n    <RequestId>27e1a1a4-638e-4d7f-81bc-f37388584eab</RequestId>\n  </ResponseMetadata>\n</AttachLoadBalancerTargetGroupsResponse>\n'
2020-05-06 10:31:20,128 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.auto-scaling.AttachLoadBalancerTargetGroups: calling handler <bound method RetryHandler.needs_retry of <botocore.retries.standard.RetryHandler object at 0x7f18da18b710>>
2020-05-06 10:31:20,129 - MainThread - botocore.retries.standard - DEBUG - Not retrying request.
2020-05-06 10:31:20,130 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event after-call.auto-scaling.AttachLoadBalancerTargetGroups: calling handler <bound method RetryQuotaChecker.release_retry_quota of <botocore.retries.standard.RetryQuotaChecker object at 0x7f18da18b438>>
2020-05-06 10:31:20,143 - MainThread - awscli.formatter - DEBUG - RequestId: 27e1a1a4-638e-4d7f-81bc-f37388584eab
root@HP:/home/bell# aws elbv2 describe-target-groups|jq -r '.[]|.[].TargetGroupArn'|cut -d/ -f2`
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but you are saying you are adding an instance to target group, but the cli command you have posted is of attaching target group to an auto scaling group. Both are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your goal is to attach an instance to the target group that used by Load Balancer.

Which the command you provided is incorrect `aws autoscaling attach-load-balancer-target-groups` is used to attached a **target group** to loadbalancer not **instance**  to target group.

To add an instance to target group in order for your loadbalancer to load balance a request you should use `aws elbv2 register-targets`

More about it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/register-targets.html)